# How to pop UIViewController when no NavigationController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

My initial scene has a navigation controller embedded. This scene links to a UITableViewController scene.  The tableview scene doesn't know anything about the navigation controller.

In the tableview scene, I've added a navigation bar and left button called back. How do I get back to the previous scene?

I have the following action associated with the back button:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

But it doesn't do anything because `self.navigationController` is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `navigationController` is `nil`, then your scene must have been `display`ed modally, not `push`ed onto a nav controller. Instead of `pop`ping it, you have to call `dismissViewController` on it.

A better approach than using a left button item to navigate is to use the nav bar's built-in functionality by setting a custom `backIndicatorImage` and mask.

Comment: How do I get the right bar button back onto the navigation bar? It doesn't want to stick since I changed the segue to push.  The bar button goes to the bottom of the scene.

Comment: The bar button has to be added to both view controllers' navigation items. Each time a vc is pushed or popped, it's navigation item is also pushed or popped in the nav bar.